# sstablesplit not working on cassandra 2.1.12

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I have a sstable having a size of 40GB which i was trying to split using the following command :

`bin/sstablesplit --no-snapshot -s 10 keyspace-columnfamily-ka-2466-Data.db`

But it deletes the current file of 40Gb and doens't even split it without giving error. What could be the possible reason or am i doing soomething wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try -v version and send the output
bin/sstablesplit -v --no-snapshot -s 10 keyspace-columnfamily-ka-2466-Data.db